# How do i find interfaces that are anyhow related to the class?

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I have an issue, i need to list all the interfaces that are anyhow related to the class? –
For ex:

```
class Test : interface1
{
    public int var1;

    classA obj1;
    classB obj2;
    classC obj3;
}

class classA: interface2
{
    testclass obj;
}

class classB: interface3
{
}

class classC: interface4
{
}

class testclass: testinterface
{ 
   myinterface objInterface;
}
interface myinterface{}
```

My question is how do I list all the interfaces of class Test (it should return all the interfaces anyhow related to the class ex:. interface1, interface2 etc.,).

Anyone help me please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: At runtime or when writing your code?

Comment: What does this have to do with LINQ?

Comment: Can is ask for what you need it? Are you writing some kind of [`ILSpy`](http://ilspy.net/) clone? I'm just curious because every hour somebody asks a reflection question and i've needed it almost never in 14 years. Maybe there's a better approach.

Comment: Are you talking about interfaces it implements or interfaces that are anyhow related to the class?

Comment: I need to find all the interfaces of the class Test. It should include all the class present in the Test class

Comment: i know how to find a class implement certain interface, i need to find class and all the subclass interfaces using linq, thats why i added linq

Comment: i need exactly the interfaces that are anyhow related to the class? –

Comment: I have changed altered my question, thanks for your input, can you please help me

Comment: Can you tell us *WHY*? Why linq? What bigger problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: i feel it will be two or three line code in linq. if i am wrong sorry. i need solution, it may be any form :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current code (almost nothing public, fields instead of properties, etc...), you could do something like that :

```
var type = typeof(Test);
var interfaces = type.GetInterfaces().ToList();
interfaces.AddRange(type.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Instance)
     .SelectMany(x => x.FieldType.GetInterfaces()));
```

this won't retrieve interfaces of `public int var1`, as it's... public.

This probably won't fit your exact needs, but without real code and real expected result, it's quite hard to give a better answer.

**EDIT**

With recursion and your sample, in a console app :

```
private static void Main()
 {
     var type = typeof(Test);
     var interfaces = type.GetInterfaces().ToList();
     GetRecursiveInterfaces(type, ref interfaces);

 }

 private static IList<Type> GetFieldsType(Type type)
 {
     return type.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).Select(m => m.FieldType).ToList();
 }

 private static void GetRecursiveInterfaces(Type type, ref List<Type> interfaces)
 {
     foreach (var innerType in GetFieldsType(type))
     {
         interfaces.AddRange(innerType.IsInterface 
                             ? new[] { innerType } 
                             : innerType.GetInterfaces());
         GetRecursiveInterfaces(innerType, ref interfaces);
     }
 }
```

Comment: No its not working, its giving me all the interfaces of collections, icomparable,ienumarable etc.,

Comment: @user1557020 it works with your sample code, and what you say you wanna retrieve from your sample code. Now, as mentioned, show real code and real expected result to have an adapted answer...

Comment: its listing only interface1 to interface4 but not listing the testinterface

Comment: @user1557020 of course : you have no field `testclass obj5;` in your Test class ! You want recursion, then ? (the "etc.") is not that helping ;)

Comment: Hi if i add the code, its not listing the member interface in the list, class testclass : testinterface
    {
        newinterface s;
    }

        public interface newinterface{}.

Comment: now i have modified a bit, you can see your code is working fine, but not listing the myinterface

Comment: @user1557020 corrected for that point (but your code won't compile, it should be something like `myinterface myinterface;`)

Comment: thanks a lot, its working fine. once again thanks for timely help. i have changed my question too, it was wrong in myinterface.